# How to handle with NULL values

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following code:

```
`SELECT nt.pl,
         o.cat,
         o.coun,
         COUNT (DISTINCT nt.im) Sub,
         SUM (nt.DOWN + nt.UP) Vol,
         COUNT (*) AS counter,
         CASE
            WHEN nt.tele = '5' THEN 'Vo'
            WHEN nt.tele = ('N/A') AND nt.rat = ('G') THEN 'G'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
         END
            AS Service
    FROM tmp nt, description o
   WHERE nt.pl = o.pl AND nt.time LIKE '201605%'
GROUP BY nt.pl,
         o.cat,
         o.coun,
         nt.tele,
         nt.rat`
```

The problem is that the column **rat** contains NULL values and in the result I receive more rows than expected. How I could handle with these NULL values.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: How do you ***need*** to handle null values?  You haven't really specified what you want to do with them when encountered.  Also what do you mean you have more rows than expected?  I'm sure we could figure it out, but try to be more specific in the problem you've encountered and what your expected outcome is.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that rather than having the `nt.tele` and `nt.rat` columns in the group by list, you want the case expression instead, e.g.:

```
  SELECT nt.pl,
         o.cat,
         o.coun,
         COUNT (DISTINCT nt.im) Sub,
         SUM (nt.DOWN + nt.UP) Vol,
         COUNT (*) AS counter,
         CASE
            WHEN nt.tele = '5' THEN 'Vo'
            WHEN nt.tele = ('N/A') AND nt.rat = ('G') THEN 'G'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
         END
            AS Service
    FROM tmp nt, description o
   WHERE nt.pl = o.pl AND nt.time LIKE '201605%'
GROUP BY nt.pl,
         o.cat,
         o.coun,
         CASE
            WHEN nt.tele = '5' THEN 'Vo'
            WHEN nt.tele = ('N/A') AND nt.rat = ('G') THEN 'G'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter the null value?

```
 WHERE nt.pl = o.pl AND nt.time LIKE '201605%' AND nt.rat is not null
```

??